# Intel Xed: Suppress Disassembly output

Tags: assembly, decode, encode, disassembly, intel-pin

I am currently using Intel XED (Intel's encoder/decoder) to decode and encode an application's instructions within Intel's Pin tool (binary rewriter). When I output disassembly in Pin with the Syntax mode set to XED, I get a lot of extra output than I need.

Example:

`TEST DISP_WIDTH:8, EASZ:2, EOSZ:2, HAS_MODRM:1, HSW, IMM_WIDTH:8, IMM0SIGNED, IMM0:0X1`

I really would just like the opcode followed by the operands in the XED format so that the XED encoder can read in the disassembly and encode it.Is there any way I can suppress the output? Or get the opcode and operands separately in a relatively pain-free manner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CHEERS,

Danny

Comment: How about a small sed script?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you used `PIN_SetSyntaxXED()` then `INS_Disassemble()` and it shows you this output as a result of the latter call? If not could you show us some code?

Comment: @Neitsa yes that is correct. I was wondering if Pin could could output instead just the opcode (in string format such as ADD) followed by the operands in XED format.